# How to activate clearInterval() after a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five squares. When I click the button, the squares move up and down with `setInterval`. The function `clearInterval` works perfectly. But what I really want is when I click to activate `clearInterval`, the method to work after the last square is down.

The HTML code follow bellow:

```
<div id="box-holder" class="down">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="button-group">
  <button id="btn-move" class="stopped">Move Box</button>
  <button id="btn-active">Active Click</button>
</div>
```

And this is the JS code:

```
var blocksInterval;
function clicked() {
    $('#btn-move').trigger('click');
}

function startClick() {
    blocksInterval = setInterval(clicked,200);
}

function stopClick() {
    clearInterval(blocksInterval);
}

$('#btn-active').click(function() {
    $(this).html('Stop');
    if( $('#btn-move').hasClass('stopped') ) {
        $('#btn-move').removeClass('stopped');
        startClick();
    } else {
        $(this).html('Active Click');
        $('#btn-move').addClass('stopped');
        stopClick();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you need some Promises...  I think though there's too much code missing to propose a full solution (e.g how's the movement performed, and if you mean animation why not sure jQuery's built-in animations) ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the number of elements that are using the animation and have the 'stopped' class. If the number of btn-move elements is the same as the number of 'stopped' elements, all elements have stopped. Changes to your click function are below:

```
$('#btn-active').click(function() {
    $(this).html('Stop');
    if( $('#btn-move').hasClass('stopped') ) {
        $('#btn-move').removeClass('stopped');
        startClick();
    } else {
        $(this).html('Active Click');
        $('#btn-move').addClass('stopped');
        // stopClick();
        if($('#btn-move').length == $('#btn-move.stopped').length){ stopClick(); }
    }
});
```